# How can I make a generic function that recursively deserializes JSON with nested datestrings type safe?

Tags: typescript, date, types, typescript-generics

The code below defines a function `stringsToDates` that will take a primitive, object, or Promise and recursively convert any ISO8601 date strings that it finds (serialized JSON) to instantiated Date objects. How can I make such a function type safe so that I could call `const result = stringsToDates<MyBusinessObject>(serializedObject)` and `result` be of type `MyBusinessObject`? I have verified the functionality (and can include the test suite if requested), but am struggling with the typing aspect.

If I were to replace the function signature with the commented line, several of the return statements throw type errors such as `Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'DateDeserialized<T>'.` Further examples are in the TS Playground included at the bottom of this section.

Code snippet:

```js
type IsoDateString = string
function isIsoDateString(value: unknown): value is IsoDateString {
    const isoDateFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d*)?Z$/;
    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return isoDateFormat.test(value);
    }
    return false;
}

type DateDeserialized<T> =
    T extends string ? Date | T :
    T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? PromiseLike<DateDeserialized<U>> :
    { [K in keyof T]: DateDeserialized<T[K]> }

function stringsToDates<T>(body: T): DateDeserialized<T> {
    if (body === null || body === undefined) {
        return body;
    } else if (body instanceof Promise) {
        return body.then(stringsToDates);
    } else if (Array.isArray(body)) {
        return body.map(stringsToDates);
    } else if (isIsoDateString(body)) {
        return new Date(body);
    } else if (typeof body !== 'object') {
        return body;
    } else {
        const bodyRecord = body;
        console.log(bodyRecord)
        return Object.keys(bodyRecord).reduce((previous, current): Record<string, any> => {
            const currentValue = bodyRecord[current];
            if (isIsoDateString(currentValue)) {
                return { ...previous, [current]: new Date(currentValue) };
            } else {
                return { ...previous, [current]: stringsToDates(currentValue) };
            }

        }, Object.create({}));
    }
}

// Example invocation
type MyBusinessObject = { foo: string, bar: Date };

const input = { foo: 'example', bar: (new Date(0)).toJSON() }
const result = stringsToDates(input); 
/* const result: {
    foo: string | Date;
    bar: string | Date;
} */
```

[Original TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL57vW)

[New TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weBkdN) courtesy of @jcalz

Comment: You're never going to get type safety when returning values that need to be assignable to generic conditional types; the compiler just defers evaluating them and therefore has no idea what might be assignable.  [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) is probably the most relevant issue about this limitation.

Comment: ... But I don't see how you could ever do what you're doing safely, since there's no type-system distinction between a `string` which is and is not a valid date. Like, what would ever prevent `stringsToDates<MyBusinessObject>({foo: "example", bar: "oopsiedoodle"})` from compiling?

Comment: I could imagine a version that outputs `string | Date` when the input is of type `string`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjXzlm); which isn't any safer in the implementation, but at least aligns with the capability of the type system.

Comment: So, how should we proceed with this question?  As asked the answer is "sorry, no" with a link to ms/TS#33912, but there are some complicating factors with the question's premise that make it hard to know what to do.  Maybe you should [edit] the `DateSerialized<T>` to the `DateDeserialized<T>` version with `string | Date` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/weBkdN) and then we can answer the question without digressing?

Comment: Thanks for the assist @jcalz. The `DateDeserialized<T>` type is what I'm looking for; looks like I got the order of serialization backwards for what would work. Having it narrowed down to `Date | string` is sufficient for my use case, I was hoping to get it narrower than the blanket `unknown` I had been using. I'll make that edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript type checker isn't currently able to do much analysis on [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which depend on as-yet-unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  It essentially *defers* evaluation of such types, and therefore treats them as *opaque*.  It doesn't know what values may or may not be assignable to such types, and it errs on the side of safety by issuing warnings about assignability.

The `DateDeserialized<T>` type is a conditional type, and inside the body of `stringsToDates()`, the type `T` is a generic type parameter and the compiler doesn't know exactly what it is.  So `DateDeserialized<T>` is opaque to the compiler, and when you return something like `body` (of type `T`), the compiler compares it to `DateDeserialized<T>`, is unable to verify whether that will work, and issues a warning like `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DateDeserialized<T>'`.  And likewise for the other return statements.

Compare this to the behavior *ouside* `stringsToDates()`.  When you call

```
const result: { foo: string | Date, bar: string | Date } =
  stringsToDates({ foo: 'example', bar: (new Date(0)).toJSON() });
```

the compiler infers that `T` has been specified with the specific type `{foo: string; bar: string}`, and therefore the return type is `DateDeserialized<{foo: string; bar: string}>`, which is no longer generic.  It evaluates the type fully as `{ foo: string | Date; bar: string | Date; }` and therefore the assignment to `result` succeeds.

So the issue with your code is the compiler's inability to analyze `DateDeserialized<T>` for generic `T`.

---

Now, you probably expected that by explicitly checking `body` of type `T`, then the compiler would be able to understand something more specific about `T` so that the type `DateDeserialized<T>` would become specific it could evaluate.  After all, if `body === null || body === undefined` is true, doesn't that mean that `T` is `null | undefined`, and then the return type would be the specific type `DateDeserialized<null | undefined>` which is just `null | undefined`?

Well, no.  The problem is that while checking `body === null || body === undefined` can tell you something straightforward about `body`, it doesn't do anything to the type parameter `T` itself.  All we know about `T` after that check is that `null` and `undefined` are in its domain; it could be `string | null` or `{a: number} | undefined` or `unknown` or anything.  And this complexity is not modeled well by the compiler, so it still gives up.

It would be great if it could do something better, though.  And there are various open feature requests about this.  The most applicable one here is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), asking for some way to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to get more useful information about conditional types in `return` statements.  If that ever gets implemented, it would presumably fix or at least improve the situation.  But for now we have to work around it.

---

The easiest workaround is to just accept that the compiler is hopelessly unprepared to do any useful type checking inside the body of a function that deals extensively with generic conditional types, and take steps to suppress the errors, via techniques like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

In cases like this I generally turn the offending function into an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function with a single call signature.  Overloads are usually used for multiple distinct call signatures, but they also allow for a barrier between the function as viewed by callers and the function as viewed by the implementer, and latter is checked fairly loosely against the former.

In your example, I'd just move the generic conditional version to the call signature, and use [the "turn off type checking" `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) in the implementation signature:

```
// call signature
function stringsToDates<T>(body: T): DateDeserialized<T>;

// implementation
function stringsToDates(body: any) {
    if (body === null || body === undefined) {
        return body;
    } else if (body instanceof Promise) {
        return body.then(stringsToDates);
    } else if (Array.isArray(body)) {
        return body.map(stringsToDates);
    } else if (isIsoDateString(body)) {
        return new Date(body);
    } else if (typeof body !== 'object') {
        return body;
    } else {
        const bodyRecord = body;
        console.log(bodyRecord)
        return Object.keys(bodyRecord).reduce((previous, current): Record<string, any> => {
            const currentValue = bodyRecord[current];
            if (isIsoDateString(currentValue)) {
                return { ...previous, [current]: new Date(currentValue) };
            } else {
                return { ...previous, [current]: stringsToDates(currentValue) };
            }

        }, Object.create({}));
    }
}
```

Now there are no errors.

Note that the lack of errors does *not* imply type safety in the body of the function.  The whole point of this workaround is to suppress the errors because the compiler is outmatched.  That means if you want type safety inside the body of the function, it will have to be verified by *you* and not by the compiler.  So I'd suggest you double and triple check the implementation to be sure that the values being returned really will be of the type `DateDeserialized<T>`, or at least close enough to be useful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgewCIENgQMrAE4EsB2A5lALxRw4GECwAUAGYCu+AxsLgvlLnPMmpkpEAFADcUAG0YQAXFGYBrfAgDu+AJRzxU6D1iJU6LHiJQA3nShWoLThW4GBAMQTYAtmlJQA9AD0AOgAmZgAsAL4AtEFmAEyR0XEAKglhMilpwXHCAPxpAHRBAFTq2QBaACTeANyW1rj0UGKS0qQkZPiMEhJQAD49UNotbWTMgRD0BBCB6ua11tbYEMCM2Fz0knAQNbTzYXPcDcKgkAgNg9DDUADkFCaEVzMWO-MLSytcPPzoLu5oeegUJo6dTbXb7RbLVZQdYSTbbPa0OjHaCGCBICCbPCSXAALymAB5EgA+Uj7RJQCAAD3Q+ECcHIQmI2SgqN6UHJMjJFOpEFp9IACtgEG4eBAADK4BQQfEEegQbBQACqJOZguFoolUvxqPRmNw2LxgXxypJnOeVjMUAA2gBpbhcKUgU7sgC6ch1GPl+okuIJiVtLpJCLoTFY7E4DLucESXwxhKJwgARghAiA5IlNCyBLqvQa-UTtqG2BwuLcqNHY3Akym01AUPgQI99vVGsnU612p1un0oG2QB35LTxpNprNzS8Ie9ezXQdYwhTYbpDn37RR6ywIM61SLNk3x-NJ1C+-8ABa84RlogV1FwEH7ecQRcHRoAQWw2BQIDyPDfH5A1dTdQ9xeV5IS4Y8PDAC9GWvARb1nKwHyfFthB4PhUWMKgAMbYCQKgQ8uHwCAVCzdBsLvcckM2Z8jnATcGhXABCNprgQRMACsIDYB4xzw-C3iPGd7wXainj42x8HsPsACUuNcQIvD7BCXgkxAJAgPIJAQQhsNk2xsGmfYDwErgAHkOK44A8kdKsZLkgz1DyRZAkYDdhGEMBFlEDhGDgAAaGwVkWfBgEzPT5PxS9CAC+sQBJEgSTEvjrFU4BAvfXlgAANWaC5p1TcKDKtFggsyl1lL4lC0McIxGWEEqMpCnLgVw5KJxM8woDybrPIgbyEF8gLitKkK3SgIiSNReqRuy3KZjCCq8Ko6Akra4ywM67q8l6-rButBrguAMaotggFpsa2bgSgBajKWuhbsQgLzM4tg8hYRYBGEMwwiA5SEWDWhUvtMBGDSshLXoBAEDkK4qRQNwwHUq4AsTFBsDkYQJtIiBhAABiA-4EAAKQwUyADlhHm+7AbsNLFjgTpgDkCGobkKK2VRFG0bZxkOYEa7SXHE6YxvVD8BB0LtjoIA)